# how to open all URLs from a CSV file using urllib2 in python 2.x

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to open all URLs from a CSV file using the following code:

```
import urllib2
import csv

f = open('listofwebsites.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
for row in csv_f:
    req = urllib2.Request(strdomain)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    html_content = response.read()

f.close()
```

I'm getting the following error: **NameError: name 'strdomain' is not defined**

How can i define `strdomain` to open each URL from the CSV files?

Comment: Is `strdomain` a column in the csv? Suppose it was column 2, counting from zero. Then you would do `req = urllib2.Request(row[2])`. Add an example csv file (a few lines will do) to make this a working example. That will help us work it out.

Comment: Also, even the urllib2 documentation recommends using the Requests package: http://docs.python-requests.org, which is much nicer to use.

Comment: @tdelaney thank you for your reply. `strdomain` is not a column in the csv. The csv only contains one column and each row contains a different URL like this:"[http://www.example.com](http://www.example.com)". I'm trying to open each URL from the csv file using the code in my post. Any suggestions?

Comment: So its not a csv, just one url per line... and I assume that url is what you call `strdomain`?

Comment: @tdelaney it is indeed one url per line, but the file extension name is ".csv". `strdomain` is a mistake i guess, this particular word/syntax was randomly added because python need one extra "argument" (sorry, I'm a beginner). Not sure if my code above is the right method to achieve my goal

Comment: It's Okay to call it a single column csv, but the `csv` module is overkill. Since there are no column delimiters, and the line does not need to be split into multiple columns, there is no need for a parser. This code should do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have one url per line in the file. You can just read the lines, strip the newline and any unintended spaces and use that.

```
import urllib2

with open('listofwebsites.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        strdomain = line.strip()
        if strdomain:
            req = urllib2.Request(strdomain.strip())
            response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
            html_content = response.read()
```

Comment: I've tried your code. I keep getting many errors, including this one: File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 556, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Comment: That's a problem with the http request, not this code. You may need to authenticate to get the data you want - for that I'd suggest using the `requests` module and reading up on its session object. Or the url is bad. As for this code, you can use a try/except block to skip bad urls and continue processing.

Comment: I got it working! Thank you so much! I now need to  automatically scrape each URL's source code to find specific keywords in it. Any idea?